# Thread window is empty

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am debugging console application, it has several threads running. Then why Thread Window is empty in VS 2010? I do not see any thread listed here, even main thread is not here. Do I need to enable something?

Comment: Might be a rendering issue.  Try clicking around where the column headers should be, or try resizing the window.

Comment: Are you using VS Express edition or more advanced?

Comment: This is pretty normal.  Set a breakpoint or use Debug + Break All.

Comment: @HansPassant - Solved the issue for me as well. Should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Seen in HansPassant's comment above: This is normal, please try to set a **breakpoint** or utilize **Debug + Break All**.